# How to filter unwanted words in a text file Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a program in Haskell that can filter out unwanted keywords from a text document. The text document contains information about persons, for example name, age and city, and I want to filter out all of the information associated to those persons who dose not fulfill the keyword.

The database looks something like this:

```
"Eric" 27 "London"
"Josefine" 34 "Stockholm"
"Hans" 50 "London"
```

So if the keyword is "London", I want the following output:

```
"Eric" 27 "London"
"Hans" 50 "London"
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways to store the information and to filter out the unwanted persons, but I'm now clueless on how this should be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exercise can be completed using only bits and pieces from the Prelude. First let's parse your text into something more structured:

```
data Person = Person {
    personName :: String,
    personAge :: Int,
    personLocation :: String
}

parse :: String -> [Person]
parse txt = let rows = map words (lines txt)
            in map (\[name, age, location] -> Person name (read age) location) rows
```

I'm using the magical power of [`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to drill down into the list produced by [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines). The lambda function I'm mapping over it is partial, though - it'll crash your program if any of the input lines are not in the correct format. In real-world code I'd be sure to handle failure more elegantly by building error-handling into my parser: I'd change the return type to [`Either String [Person]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either) and return `Left "an error message"` if it failed to parse. Parser libraries like [Parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) provide error handling out of the box.

Now we can straightforwardly [`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) out the people we're not interested in.

```
londonPeople :: [Person] -> [Person]
londonPeople = filter (\p -> personLocation p == "London")
```

Printing the output is simple too:

```
personToString :: Person -> String
personToString (Person name age location) = unwords [name, show age, location]
```

We can plug together the pieces into a program:

```
input = "Eric 27 London\nJosefine 34 Stockholm\nHans 50 London"

main = let people = parse input
           output = map personToString (londonPeople people)
       in putStrLn (unlines output)
```

And running it produces the expected output.

```
$ runhaskell people.hs
Eric 27 London
Hans 50 London
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works as intended. I'll just modify it a bit to fit my program :)